# Create new divs in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building an app with NextJS where users can report bugs thanks to a form with a description and some screenshots of the bugs.

But I have some trouble with the screenshots part.

When a user upload a screenshot of the bug, I add it to a screenshots State array. And I want to show these uploaded screenshots in the form.

And I don't know how to create div elements each time a screenshot is uploaded through the form (one div for each screenshot uploaded).

I've tried to use the createElement() method to create a div with the screenshot in background-image, then append this div to my screenshotsList element (a flexbox) with appendChild():

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let newElem = createElement("div", {
      className: "screenshot",
    });
    attachmentsRef.current.appendChild(newElem);
  }, [newBug.attachments]);
```

(attachmentsRef is a ref of my screenshotsList flexbox).

But I've got this error message:

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node

What would you do to perform that? Is there a simpler way to do what I need?

Let me know if I need to share anything else.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use `appendChild` in react it means you are doing something wrong. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists

Comment: if a new screenshot arrives in a collection - just iterate over it in your render portion

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'm new to React and NextJS, sorry in advance for my newbie questions.

I've created a <Screenshot /> component with the screenshot in its props. Then, in my form, I map over the bug screenshots:

{newBug.attachments.map((a) => {
                <Screenshot background={a} />;
})}

My question is: why doesn't it re-render when a new screenshot is uploaded and added to newBug.attachments?